# Vertically align some text to top and some to bottom on same page

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I know how to vertically align text with Word 2007. However, I would like to vertically align some text at the top and some text at the bottom, all on the same page.  I tried doing this by adding a continuous section break (one that does not go to the next page), and having different vertical alignment settings on each side of the section break. However, the vertical alignment on the other side of the section break remains the same, i.e. aligned to the top. Does anyone know of another way to make this work?

Comment: Use the footer and header?

Comment: See also: [Align paragraph to the bottom of the page in Microsoft Word - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/851806/align-paragraph-to-the-bottom-of-the-page-in-microsoft-word) (or  https://web.archive.org/web/20210329112712/http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/BottomLine.htm , which is similar but for a different purpose)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track.  Eliminate your Section Break and split your text into two paragraphs.  Then in Page Layout settings select Justified for your vertical alignment.  Anything in your top paragraph should orient to the top, anything in the second paragraph to the bottom.  If you need new lines in these paragraphs, use a carriage return <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Note, this solution doesn't allow for very complex formatting on the page, so if you need a complex layout, you should consider options like Text Boxes or filling the between paragraph gap with "empty" paragraphs as placeholders.

Comment: I usually change the paragraph spacing for individual paragraph for spacing, as inserting paragraphs have less control over the content.
However, I would love to use dynamic spacing between paragraphs, something like `\vskip # plus # minus #` in plain-TeX. I don't assume the newest version have something like that yet?

Comment: I agree that using "empty" paragraphs isn't a very good method-but through Word 2010 I haven't found anything better.  I haven't worked with any newer versions, so I'm not sure if there's a better alternative now.  I've considered learning latex as an alternative, but for the amount of documents that I do, it's been more effective to bend Word a little rather than learn an all new system.

Comment: By placing the top and bottom content in an embedded document, you can use normal `enter`s and tables without vertical spacing issues.