# Align paragraph to the bottom of the page in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

In LaTeX, one could use `\vfill` before a paragraph to align it to the bottom of the page. Is there a similar function in Microsoft Word 2007? I am trying to avoid multiple new lines or text boxes since the contents of the page will change

Comment: As far as I know there is no such option. I'd revert to a textbox or a table (which can be anchored to the bottom of the page).

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Change-the-vertical-alignment-of-text-on-a-page-fbfbe38f-3f93-4548-b26b-100a08671ba7

Comment: https://www.google.se/?gfe_rd=cr&safe=off#safe=off&q=vertically%20align%20text%20in%20word

Comment: @Hannu These instruction seem to only work on separate pages. I'm not able to make a paragraph align at the bottom if the page already has text at the top

Comment: @agtoever It works with a table the size of the page, using two cells with top alignment for the top cell and bottom alignment for the bottom cell. Though not very elegant, it's probably the best solution. Could you post it as an answer?

Comment: @Timmy: I agree. It's not elegant, but it looks like the only solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like in the old days of HTML, creating a table that has the size of the entire page with two rows will do the trick. You can anchor the table to the page. Inside each table cell, you can select horizontal and vertical alignment.

As an alternative, you can create one table cell, make sure the document text goes around or above & below it and anchor the table to the bottom of the page. Set the row height to fit. This way, you don't have the disadvantages of the table (eg different behavior of <kbd>tab</kbd>) in the regular body text.

Actually, I've seen official internal document templates of a company that used this trick to layout its text for project templates etc.

Comment: This is quitte useful for me, as what I would like to align to the bottom is a table. However it has a preceeding title-like non-table-row paragraph before it. Do you have any suggestion how can I align that table with that paragraph before it? I would not like to use textboxes either.
I wanted to use Vertical alignment with Word 2016, but that would stretch the table of contents before it.

Comment: @AdamL.S. you can achieve this with two-rows-one-column table. Put title-like paragraph into the top row and configure vertical alignment to top for it. Put the second paragraph into the bottom row and set alignment to bottom for it. You can change height of rows to move text in the top row. Make table borders invisible (0px or white color)

Answer (score 5):

The cleanest way to do this is to use page setup dialogue (under Layout in the ribbon)
Make sure to add section break before and after the text you wish to be on the bottom of the page. Always start new section on a new page.

[image: Page setup]

Comment: What about when you have a section at the end of a page that  you want to align to the bottom?

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question but it is possible with *frames*, an old feature of Word that Microsoft, for some reason, no longer exposes by default in the Word user interface. Frames are similar to text boxes but the text in them remains part of the main document. Note that this means that if you add text before the framed paragraph, it can move off the page you set it up on and onto the next one!

1. Select the paragraph you want to align
2. In the Ribbon, choose View, Macros, View Macros or hold down <kbd>ALT</kbd> and type <kbd>T</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>. The Macros dialog box will open.
3. Type `InsertFrame` and click Run (this is a poorly-documented feature of Word; if you know the name of a command, typing its name into the Macro dialog will run it). Word will convert the paragraph into a frame.
4. Double-click the Frame border, or right-click and choose Format Frame. The Frame dialog will open.
5. Change the Vertical Position drop-down to "Bottom" (the Relative To drop-down should update automatically to "Margin) and click OK.
6. By default, Word puts a border around frames. Right-click and choose Borders & Shading to get rid of it.

If you find yourself using frames a lot, you can put it back on the user interface by using the Customize dialog.

Comment: This, I believe, is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

I came across slightly different way to do this.

1. Create a single cell table (it can be border-less)
2. Put your text in the single cell
3. Go to the table properties
4. On the Table tab, set the "Text Wrapping" to "Around"
5. Click on the "Positioning" button
6. Leave the Horizontal Position and Relative fields as is (Left/Column)
7. Set the Vertical Relative field to "Page"
8. Set the Vertical Position field to a reasonable values (e.g., a single line worked well at 9.5" on letter sized pages - you can override the defaults in the pull down).
9. Click OK to leave the `Table Positioning` window.
10. Click OK to leave the `Table Properties` window

Your table (and contained text) will now float at the bottom of the page. You'll have to update the position if you change the page size of course, but you don't have to pad the bottom of the table with white space so the text doesn't sit in the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the bottom margin and adjust the footer to accommodate the text.  Place the text in the footer and add a page number under the text, if needed.  (You can use page field code if you want.)  Place a section break at the bottom of the page so that the bottom margin and footer for the subsequent pages can be restored to their desired settings.

Answer (score 0):

For me the best solution is to use a `Simple Text Box`:

- Click the Text Box button in the Insert > Text group.
- Select Simple Text Box from the gallery and enter your text.
- Open the layout options, at the bottom `show more` (in german it is `Weitere anzeigen`)
- Select Alignment:Bottom and measured(?) from page

[image]

Then starting to add content from the first line, the Text-Box will move to the bottom of the next page if needed:

[image]

Be aware, if you start to insert content not from the first line, the Text-Box will not move!:

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Simply create a textbox and under format>arrange>align select align bottom

Comment: The OP has specifically requested a solution that does not use text boxes