# How to align two sections in one page to the top and to the bottom with complex layout?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, text-editing, margins

I want to replicate this PDF page into a word document

[image: The PDF]
But I cannot make the bottom paragraph to become as I want to it to be seen.

I've already seen and tried [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/745074/vertically-align-some-text-to-top-and-some-to-bottom-on-same-page), but using that method, two paragraphs (one at the bottom and the other on the top) justified, is not the best way to align them, specially when i am trying to edit the bottom paragraph with a "special layout".

[image: The Word Document]

**EDIT:**

I could achieve similar layout using a table, but still, could there be any way to accomplish without tables and textboxes?
[image: Using tables solution]

Is there a possible way to solve this without using Textboxes?

**EDIT2:**

Since the two answers posted on this page, I was hoping for a way to get this decent layout without using tables, textboxes and without manually adding these new lines:

[image: Manually entering new lines]

The idea of my layout is to be reused as a template for crafting many documents, and the editing time of every page must not be entering text straightforward 
 without worrying about about the layout since they would be already preset.

I finally post my final solution:

[image: Solution gif]

Comment: First remove *all* formatting, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/clear-all-text-formatting-c094c4da-7f09-4cea-9a8d-c166949c9c80 , then apply correct formatting (e.g. left-justified, tab stops, etc.) to each paragraph.

Comment: that still wouldn't allow me to have to pieces of text to the top and to the bottom

Comment: @yokki that's a good idea, given that two users say using tables is the only way, i am considering using tables instead for the final document printing. But I am really intrigued how to achieve this layout without tables. Could some one explain why it can't be? if so, I will mark that as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the other solutions achieve the same final layout, I consider this to be the answer for my question.
[image: Table with borders]

1. Use a table, the editing would be as you see on the above picture,
2. Create a table: 3 rows, 2 columns
3. Make the table fit the window
4. Make the last row align to the bottom
5. Edit the margins as you want

The importance of the bottom alignment it is because of the easier it makes adding text to the publisher info of the last row, when you press Enter for a newline it makes all the paragraph go up for adding more info, convenient!.

[image: Final solution , bottom aligned]

Answer (score 3):

Use 2 columns (not table columns) for the upper part of the document. Write what need to be in that section, select them, then go to Page Layout > Page Setup > Columns > Two. Then insert a column break where the first column ends/should end.

[image: Page setup]

Next step is to insert a continuous section break. You can write the lower part and format it.

[image: Example document]

Comment: You are right, using columns is how I am editing my document as it is the only way I could have solved at the moment. But the real question is how to achieve this without tables?

Comment: I did not use tables but created columns via page setup (see additional image). That's a;so why I left the paragraph marks shown so you can see where the breaks are.

Comment: While this is a solution, honestly, this is not the answer i was looking for, i explain this on the EDIT2 of my question. PD: upvoted